# Could deutrium oxide be used to make organic compounds with Deutrium instead of hydrogen?

Tags: molecular-biology

I am wondering for prokaryotes if Deutrium Oxide could be made into Deutrium Glucose or other biological compounds with Deutrium.

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic on Biology unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see our homework policy. Moreover, this question is not really about biology.

Comment: I am sorry that this is not for biology but this is not homework. I am a Freshman in High School. I am currently learning about Meiosis and Genetics. If this is not biology then what would it be? It relates to living organisms, and it ain't physics.

Comment: We don't mean homework just in the literal sense. For any query that you have out of interest or as a result of your academic courses, you should make an attempt at finding out the answer yourself with whatever resources that you have and can understand. Did you try simply googling this query? Your query relates to isotope exchange which I would consider a chemistry question. If your query was more about whether organisms can survive and function properly with deuteriated biomolecules, then it may be considered a biological question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible and inter alia used to clarify biosynthetic pathways.

For example in this [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/8692014/). Rats were given deuterated water and the average number of D atoms incorporated in cholesterol and fatty acids was determined. Also deuterium was found in plasma glucose and liver lactate and pyruvate.